# Trying to Display ' apostrophe

Tags: math-mode

I need to get what's on the screenshot. I have tried it by using this:

```
$\text{\textbf{x}}^{'}$
```

but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: Is it an apostrophe in text mode you  want?

Comment: I don’t know. Maybe not. I just need to get what’s on the screenshot

Comment: Oh! I see. Just write `$\mathbf{x'}$`. It's not an apostrophe, but a prime symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tastes are always personal and subjective. For example, to write the apostrophe in mathematical mode some LaTeX users use the command `\prime`. In the first example `x'` is all in bold. In the second example it is only the `x` in bold.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\texttt{First mode:} $\bm{\mathrm{x}^{\prime}}$

\texttt{Second mode:} $\bm{\mathrm{x}}^{\prime}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that simply typing

```
$\mathbf{x'}$
```

Comment: I prefer `\mathbf{x}'`. You don't want to make the prime bold. (Using `\mathbf` the prime doesn't come bold anyway, but that's not the point.)